# JQuery mobile $.post is undefined

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

My function returned undefined and I am unsure how to find the data I am looking for.

```
function getCustomerName(){

       var account = localStorage.getItem("account");

       $.post("http://127.0.0.1/getCustomer.php", {account:account}, function(data) {

              alert('Inside getCustomer' + ' ' + data);

       } ,"json");

}
```

while getCustomer.php returns

```
{"nameCustomer":[{"Alarms":"0","Name":"Jane Doe"}]}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You need to use callbacks.

Comment: Could you point me to an example of this please?

Comment: I have used jsonp with callback before but I am unsure how to post/get while using it?

Comment: you have to create another function to handle the data. Inside your $.post scope, instead of alerting the data, call that other function passing the data as an argument, so it will execute as soon as the $.post is successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the call is async, when getCustomerName is finished executing, the data won't have been returned from the server. getCustomerName needs to take a callback function:

```
function getCustomerName(onNameRetrieved){
   var account = localStorage.getItem("account");

   $.post("http://127.0.0.1/getCustomer.php", {account:account}, function(data) {
       onNameRetrieved(data) //or more likely something like onNameRetrieved(data['nameCustomer'][0]['name'];
   } ,"json");
}
```

you then call getCustomerName like

```
getCustomerName(function (name) {
    alert('The actual name is ' + name);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript actually looks OK. You have a callback function in there. Remember that the `datatype` parameter specifies the return type coming back from the server not the parameter type being sent to the server. Insure that your service is expecting JSON as a parameter. Also verify that your retrieval of the `account` form localStorage is correctly returning a valid value.